# Dequeue Divi's external stylesheet and add it inline for pagination pages

Tags: php, wordpress, divi

I'm using the Divi plugin for WordPress and encountering an issue specifically on pagination pages. Divi has a feature "Load Dynamic Stylesheet In-line", however, this feature doesn't apply to pagination pages. Due to this limitation, I'm trying to implement a solution that dequeues the external Divi stylesheet and instead adds it inline only for pagination pages.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
// This function should add the Divi styles inline in the head of the document for pagination pages
function inline_divi_css_on_pagination_pages() {
    if (is_paged()) {
        $response = wp_remote_get('https://xxx.cz/wp-content/plugins/divi-builder/css/style-static.min.css?ver=4.17.4');
        if (!is_wp_error($response)) {
            $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
            echo '<style id="divi-builder-style-inline-inline-css" type="text/css">' . $body . '</style>';
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'inline_divi_css_on_pagination_pages');

// This function should dequeue the Divi external stylesheet for pagination pages
function dequeue_divi_stylesheet_on_pagination_pages() {
    if (is_paged()) {
        wp_deregister_style('divi-builder-style-css');
        wp_dequeue_style('divi-builder-style-css');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_divi_stylesheet_on_pagination_pages', 20);
```

Expected Result:

For pagination pages:

1. The Divi external stylesheet link  should be removed from the source.
2. The styles from style-static.min.css should be added inline within a  tag in the head of the document.